# xml string root element missing exception /tcp/ip listener (code and string attached)

Tags: c#, xml, sockets, tcp, console-application

hello i have read about 15 different sites about this error yet i cant fix it i blame my lack of xml parsing /streaming and reading experience if anyone can help me fix this problem they will win a fluffy kitten with mind control powers

// le tcp ip listener code

```
requestCount = requestCount + 1;
NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[100025];
networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
string dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("what the devil must i use here i tried <Monkey> but it fails"));
```

//le xml string

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <Monkey>

            <Chicken>
                                <Cow>Brown</Cow>
                               <CowID>123MOOO</CowID>
            </Chicken>
    </Monkey>
```

//Parse and upload data to db

```
    var Monkey= XDocument.Parse(dataFromClient)
                 .Descendants("Monkey")
                 .Select(n => new
                 {
                     Amount = n.Element("Cow").Value,
                     TellNo = n.Element("COwID").Value

                 });



                foreach (var item in Monkey)
                {
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("StringlistenerUpdate", conn);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("CowType", item.Cow));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("CowUniqueID", item.CowID));

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    conn.Close();
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}", item.Cow, item.CowID);
                }
```

please help and extra motivation the mind-control fluffy kitten  can talk !!!

Comment: How do you know when the client is done sending data? Do they close the connection, or do they send some sort of token in the message? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: they close the connection after the string is sent the problem is i had $ in indexof but then i get a outofrange exception cannot be les than 0 error all the information i have is just that string and i need to recieve it parse it and upload the contents to a db i tried inserting <Monkey> there but then it gives me root element missing exception so if you look at the string what do i need to do for this to work please explain or help either way i will be very grateful

Comment: Do you need to insert the whole xml string into the database?

Comment: no only cow id and cow which i have already parsed i will post that part of the code if i must

Comment: please help this is actually very important and i am getting hammered from all sides thats why i am willing to give away the talking fluffy mind control kitten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should change your code so that your XML string contains only what was uploaded. The way the code is now you are getting a string for all 100025 bytes of the buffer.

```
int count = networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
string dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom, 0, count);
```

Now `dataFromClient` is just what was sent from the client.

The last step is to parse this properly with XmlDocument class.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(dataFromClient);

string cow = doc.SelectSingleNode("Monkey/Chicken/Cow").InnerText;
string cowId = doc.SelectSingleNode("Monkey/Chicken/CowID").InnerText;
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to use XDocument class here is one way you could do it. First select all Chicken elements with an XPath statement. Next grab the child elements Cow & CowID. Note the element names are case sensitive and must match your source elements. One of the problems with your implementation was character case in "CowID".

```
var Monkey = XDocument.Parse(x).XPathSelectElements("Monkey/Chicken")
         .Select(n => new
         {
             Amount = n.Element("Cow").Value,
             TellNo = n.Element("CowID").Value

         });
```

Comment: i updated my question with my code i used to parse please look through it i appreciate your help alot

Comment: also at index of what should i put there so i dont get root element is missing exception

Comment: You dont need the line: `dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("what the devil must i use here i tried <Monkey> but it fails"));` Just make sure you are calling ASCII.GetString the way I am in the answer.

Comment: i tried it then i get the data at the root level is invalid does this make sense ? and the code i am using to parse the xml string is it correct

Comment: if we can get this to work i will really be very grateful for everything you have done

Comment: Updated my answer to include using XDocument.

Comment: thanks before i mark as answer one last question will it be able to continuously listen and parse the incoming string and do you know how to use soap to make the changes to my db??

Comment: In order to run continuously, you'll need a loop around your accept connection and read methods. Example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397809(v=vs.90).aspx. To make changes to your database via soap, you will need a web service, that will accept the soap requests, then do the the necessary database operations. Example: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/inserting-data-into-database-using-wcf-service/

Comment: thanks mike your a legend in my eyes really helped me alot thanks for your time should i send the fluffy talking mind control kitten to you now or would later be more appropriate ? its gonna be air mailed so it will take awhile also try not to take over the world ;)